# sed + how to append complex line after match specific line

Tags: linux, bash, sed

We want to append with sed , the following complex line after  matching the line that start with – `number_of_cars_are`

```
more /tmp/orig_file

number_of_cars_are=$number_of_cars_are
```

the line that we want to add:

```
numbers=` su hdfs -c "hdfs dfs -ls  $var/*.jar" |sed s'/\// /g' | awk '{print $NF}' | wc -m `
```

so we did the following

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*number_of_cars_are =.*/a numbers=` su hdfs -c "hdfs dfs -ls  $var/*.jar" |sed s'/\// /g' | awk '{print $NF}' | wc -m `' /tmp/orig_file > /tmp/new_file
```

but we get the following

```
sed: can't read /g | awk {print: No such file or directory
sed: can't read } | wc -m `: No such file or directory
```

so we try also to add backslash as

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*number_of_cars_are =.*/a numbers=` su hdfs -c \"hdfs dfs -ls  $var/*.jar\" |sed s'/\// /g' | awk '{print \$NF}' | wc -m `' /tmp/orig_file > /tmp/new_file
```

but the same

```
sed: can't read /g | awk {print: No such file or directory
sed: can't read $NF} | wc -m `: No such file or directory
```

any advice how to add the lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to put the Sed commands in a file, so that the shell does not try to interpret the special symbols of the (wanna-be) appended line.

**`longline.sed`**:

```
/^[[:space:]]*number_of_cars_are=/a\
numbers=` su hdfs -c "hdfs dfs -ls  $var/*.jar" |sed s'/\\// /g' | awk '{print $NF}' | wc -m `
```

See that the only modification is to escape a backslash, because Sed interprets escaped characters.

```
$ sed -f longline.sed newfile
more /tmp/orig_file

number_of_cars_are=$number_of_cars_are
numbers=` su hdfs -c "hdfs dfs -ls  $var/*.jar" |sed s'/\// /g' | awk '{print $NF}' | wc -m `
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `heredoc` `<<` feature to good use in this scenario.

```
repl=$(cat - <<\eof |\
sed -e 's:[\&/]:\\&:g'
numbers=` su hdfs -c "hdfs dfs -ls  $var/*.jar" |sed s'/\// /g' | awk '{print $NF}' | wc -m `
eof
)
```

```
$ sed \
    -e '/^[[:blank:]]*number_of_cars_are=/G' \
    -e "s/\\n/&$repl/" \
 /tmp/orig_file
```

As a first step, use the heredoc to print the line you want appended and process it to escape the RHS s/// characters and store it in the variable repl.

Then we plug it in the s/// rhs section on the selected line.

Note this method is eminently Posixly and doesn't require any files.It assumes uniline repl.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that a single quoted string can't ever contain a single quote. To provide the inserted line on the command line, you would have to break out of the single quoted string, add a quoted single quote, and then continue the string.  Each single quote would therefore be written as either `'\''` or as `'"'"'`, where the two flanking single quotes end and starts, respectively, the single quoted string before and after the single quote.

To avoid having to take too make extra precautions, you can instead provide the line that you want to insert as a text in a document.

Similar to [Quasímodo's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/610519/116858), but using a quoted here-document, possibly directly from the command line:

```
sed -f /dev/stdin file <<'END_SED'
/^number_of_cars_are/a\
numbers=` su hdfs -c "hdfs dfs -ls  $var/*.jar" |sed s'/\// /g' | awk '{print $NF}' | wc -m `
END_SED
```

Since the here-document is quoted (indicated by the single quotes around the initial `END_SED` delimiter), none of the expansion in it will be expanded by the shell.

The `sed` utility reads the here-document from its standard input using `-f /dev/stdin`.